# Office365APIs : How to handle and expired Access Token

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

The Office365API provides a nice way to get an access token but there are no example on how to handle the situation when the token expires. Moreover, there does not seem to be a refresh token.

On the blog "How to: Integrate Office 365 with a web server app using Common Consent Framework"
[ [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605894(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605894%28v=office.15%29.aspx) ] there is the notion of getting a refresh token along with the access token. When the access token expires the refresh token can be used to get another access token / refresh token set without requiring the user to log into their office 365 account again.

Does anyone know how to handle the expired access token using the Office365APIs?

Answer (score 0):

The way i do it is

```
await _outAuthenticationInfo.ReauthenticateAsync(ExchangeResourceId);
```